# How i can receive one object instead many using spring JdbcTemplate when i using inner join comand in sql?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, jdbctemplate

I have a class User with fields:

```
private Long id;
private String u_name;
private String u_surname;
private int u_age;
private Set<Roles> roles = new HashSet<>(); //its enum
```

When i tried to display it in response using JdbcTemplate and rest controller I have a problem because i receive three object in it.

My repository classes:

```
public List<User> findAll() {
    String sql = "select users.id, users.u_name, users.u_surname, users.u_age, user_roles.user_role from users inner join user_roles on users.id = user_roles.user_id";
    return jdbc.query(sql, new RowMapper<User>(){
        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
            Set<Roles> roles = new HashSet<>();
            roles.add(Roles.valueOf(rs.getString("user_role")));
            return new User(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("u_name"), rs.getString("u_surname"), rs.getInt("u_age"), roles);
        }

    });
}

public User findById(Long id) {
    String sql = "select users.id, users.u_name, users.u_surname, users.u_age, user_roles.user_role from users inner join user_roles on users.id = user_roles.user_id where users.id = ?";
    return jdbc.queryForObject(sql, new RowMapper<User>(){
        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
            Set<Roles> roles = new HashSet<>();
            roles.add(Roles.valueOf(rs.getString("user_role")));
            return new User(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("u_name"), rs.getString("u_surname"), rs.getInt("u_age"), roles);
        }

    }, id);
}
```

What do I need to do to receive only one object instead many?

Comment: [receive three object] which three... , [expect only one object] which one...

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you probably have more then one role attached to your user, so your SQL will result in a matrix (more roles, more lines), to solve that you will have to remove the join, but only if you don't need to see roles. However, if you have to retrieve user that has roles, you can change your sql to use 'exists' like that:

```
select 
    users.id, 
    users.u_name, 
    users.u_surname, 
    users.u_age, 
    user_roles.user_role 
from users 
where exists (
    select 1 from user_roles 
    where users.id = user_roles.user_id)
and users.id = ?
```

*haven't tested

If, after all, you really need to know the roles, i recommend you to create a separate method to retrieve them